# Flask-WTForms- Calling field list entires individually in template

Tags: python, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Say if I have a FieldList that contains two fields (but up to a max of 5 allowed entries like so:

```
class NameForm(Form):
    firstname = StringField('firstname')
    surname = StringField('surname')

class Combine(Form):
    combination = FieldList(FormField(NameForm), min_entries=1, max_entries=5)
```

If I want to call each entry individually to be displayed in the template I've read I need to call each by it's index.

In my template I've tried calling like so:

```
{{ form.description.description-0 }}
```

for wachi I get an error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

I've also tried the following:

```
{{ form.combination(index="combination-0") }}
```

Which does produce the two fields for one of the potential entries in the combination form. However, when I change the number to either 1, 2 3, or 4 (to represent each of the indexes up to the maximum)  the displayed on screen entry/index doesn't change as it's still labeled combination-0 in the gui.
Am I calling the index correctly or just barking up the wrong tree?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to iterate it most likely:

```
{% for entry in form.combination %}
    {{ entry.form.firstname }}
    {{ entry.form.surname }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternately, if you must get the 2nd entry, you can do

```
{{ form.combination.entries[1].firstname }}
```

And the like.

Note that unless there's form data to create more entries, you're going to get an IndexError trying to index nonexistent entries. `min_entries=1` only guarantees at least one entry.

If you want to programmatically add entries, use [`append_entry`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList.append_entry).